# How to stack all non blank cells from a column?

Tags: google-sheets

Here is the same question and its answer for Excel. I want this method for Google Sheets.

https://superuser.com/questions/1623756/how-can-i-stack-all-non-blank-cells-from-a-column/1830491#1830491

I am looking for a formula that will take all non-blank values in one column and stack them in another column.

Please see example below. Essentially I am trying to go from column A to B using a formula:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | Apple |
| 2 |  | Orange |
| 3 | Orange | Lemon |
| 4 | Lemon | Pear |
| 5 |  | Banana |
| 6 |  |  |
| 7 | Pear |  |
| 8 |  |  |
| 9 | Banana |  |

I have tried the following formula, but it seems to only replicate column A.

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$9,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$9<>"",ROW($A$1:$A$9)-ROW($A$1)+1),ROWS($A$1:$A1))),"")`

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Using `TOCOL()` function in Google Sheets

[image]

---

```
=TOCOL(A1:A,1)
```

---

Or, its better to use `FILTER()` function:

```
=IFNA(FILTER(A1:A,A1:A<>""),"")
```

---

**Edit:**

As suggested by **[Blindspots](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/197518/blindspots)** Sir, few short alternative versions, which takes care of the errors as well, when there is no data, and will return `#REF!` error using `TOCOL()` therefore using the following which will not occur:

Using `TOCOL()`

```
={TOCOL(A:A,1);IFNA(#N/A)}
```

[image]

---

Or, Using with `FILTER()`

```
=IFNA(FILTER(A:A,LEN(A:A)),)
```

---

Comment: Sir, I am not familiar and well versed with Google Sheets, also, I found while using `TOCOL()` if there is no reference and using `IFERROR()` it was still showing `#REF!` error but using `FILTER()` it wasnt so I have said.

Comment: @Blindspots the answer has a point. When the column is blank, `tocol(A1:A, 1)` will error out, and that error cannot be caught the normal way. To catch the error, you need to use `filter()` or friends. In my opinion, `A1:A` is preferable to `A:A`, because that way nothing will break if you later insert a header row.

Comment: @doubleunary you are simply creating your own conditions that don't currently exist. It is also possible that the OP could possibly  want to copy the formula somewhere else and that would change the row number and the column. Maybe the row and/or the column  should be absolute. I'm simply making a statement about what is more efficient. Whether one is better than the other requires additional requirements which needn't favor the less efficient approach.

Comment: @Blindspots Sir, no it will still return `#REF!` error . **[Here is a screenshot](https://imgur.com/gallery/PWvl7r9)** , I came across this problem while giving a solution in Stackoverflow, for Excel tag, where upon OP, after accepting the answer said the formula is not working and they are using Google Sheets. Even wrapping within `IFERROR()` it doesn't go away. it still exisit.

Comment: You are correct. I tested `=TOCOL(A:A, 2)` successfully didnt expect `=TOCOL(A:A, 3)` to reintroduce it. So, `=TOCOL(A:A, 1)`  isn't a good option if there may be absolutely no values in the column and a `#REF! ` error is undesirable. I find the behavior intriguing and will look into it further. `=IFNA(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""),)` is   then pretty short.  I did find the following works as well and shaves a few more characters off and makes it more peculuar: `={TOCOL(A:A,1);IFNA(#N/A)}`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my error. 

Comment: You included a lot of great info in your comments that should be [edited](/posts/173894/edit) into your answer so that they are available to future readers. Thank you for pointing out my errors.

Comment: Wow great stuff that is with curly brackets, works a treat this is really nice

Comment: I don't think mine is *better*, it is only 3 chars less and as I noted in my response to doubleunary's comment, what is "best" will differ based on scenario. You could show both options to increase the toolkit for others and explain the reason why simply `=TOCOL(A:A, 1)` *"might"* be an issue.

Comment: @Blindspots re _"making a statement about what is more efficient"_ — for the record, `filter(A1:A, A1:A <> "")` is about twice as fast as `tocol(A1:A, 1)`, and `filter(A1:A, isnumber(A1:A))` is another 50% faster still. Be aware that `{TOCOL(A:A,1);IFNA(#N/A)}` has a side-effect: it appends a blank value at the bottom. The question specifies _"take all non-blank values"_ so the formula should not be adding one. The reason why null arrays throw a reference error is that Google Sheet formulas are expected to return either a single value or a 2D array, and the concept of `[[]]` is not supported.

Comment: @doubleunary True, and `=IFNA(filter(A:A, A:A <> ""))` returns a blank value if no matches are made.  Efficiency as a function of code length or efficiency as a function of calculation speed  may be more or less attractive depending on the use case. Returning blanks instead of errors may not be desirable or returning an extra blank may be irrelevant. It's good to know the info you shared and I always appreciate the additional info. I think that `TOCOL(A:A, 1)` will likely be perfect for their needs but if not we'd need to know what their needs are to make this more meaningful.

Comment: I like making code shorter. You like making it faster. I do like it to be faster if it's running slowly, but don't give it precedence if I can't perceive the difference.  If we control the requirements we can show how our approach best fits them. If the OP controls them then we have less freedom to argue for requirements that we are introducing ourselves.  I expect the OP just wants to remove some gaps from their data. I presume there is data to remove the gaps from and the `TOCOL(x, 1)` will be more than adequate. I do appreciate the info about the relative speed.

Comment: _"You like making it faster."_ What.