# How can you copy and bunch words into a different column?

Tags: google-sheets

I was wondering if there was a way to return the contents of a column but skip the blank rows to better utilize the space.

I have tried researching this, but have not found anything. Every solution I found copied the words but would not remove the empty rows.

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Original** |  | **Desired Result** |
| **2** | word 1 |  | word 1 |
| **3** |  |  | word 2 |
| **4** | word 2 |  | word 3 |
| **5** | word 3 |  | word 4 |
| **6** |  |  | word 5 |
| **7** | word 4 |  |  |
| **8** |  |  |  |
| **9** |  |  |  |
| **10** | word 5 |  |  |

[Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cf94Rzp2Di4JOPd0GKtM720_TvgbFAb_sN_OVknk2dA/edit#gid=2100307022)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your question Nolan. It now appears to be a duplicate of  [How to stack all non-blank cells from a column?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/173887/how-to-stack-all-non-blank-cells-from-a-column)  There is a great answer there.  If you find it helpful remember to upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

need permission to access the page, but what you're describing sounds like concatenation, which would be done like this:

=CONCATENATE(A1,B1)

If you want anything in between the values, you can add that inside inverted commas, like this:

=CONCATENATE(A1," ", B1)

Hope this helps!